# How can I calculate Kernel matrix K for clustering based Kernel Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, bigdata, pca

In practice, a large data set leads to a large K, and storing K may become a problem. One way to deal with this is to perform clustering on the dataset, and populate the kernel with the means of those clusters for speeding up and reducing storage.
How can I calculate the kernel using clustering?

Answer (score 1):

Foremost, we must understand what is `clustering`.

It is an unsupervised algorithm, applicable to scenario's where the target class is unknown. So essentially it's a data preprocessing algorithm. Continuing further, `cluster analysis`, helps in detecting `patterns` in data. Now, to detect patterns in data, one must ensure the `sample` consist of `statistically significant` variables. To find such significant variables, we need to perform various data preprocessing tasks like `outlier`, `missing value('s)`, `correlation` and `dimensionality reduction` detection and treatment. Post, performing these steps, the `noise` from the data would be removed and one would be able to reveal the `signal`. Otherwise, one can perform the `principal component analysis (pca)` to detect the signal. This signal('s), can then aid in determining the true patterns or `clusters` in the data.

Now, coming to the second part of the question. You can use the `kernlab` package in `R` to calculate the kernel. Perhaps these posts can help you further, [1](https://rpubs.com/sandipan/205018), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621642/assign-new-data-point-to-cluster-in-kernel-k-means-kernlab-package-in-r), [3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html), [4](https://www.r-bloggers.com/learning-kernels-svm/).

Comment: @thanks for your answer. Do you have any matlab package

Comment: Maybe my question is a little different! It is clustering based KPCA. It may useful for big data on KPCA

Comment: @KMIbrahimKhalilullha check this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html) for matlab package in R.